# EditText onChangeListener function Android

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

I have the following code:

```
nameOfInf.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {
    if (strTollAmount.length() > 0) {
        nameOfInf.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.white));
        nameOfInf.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.black));
    }
});
tollAmount.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {
    if (strInfName.length() > 0) {
        tollAmount.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.white));
        tollAmount.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.black));
    }
});
```

The function checks to see if the value on the textbox is anything other than empty or null. So if the user enters something in the text box the background and foreground color should change. But that's not happening. Any idea how to edit it?

Comment: Is it compiles? I think `TextBox2 > ""` shouldn't compile.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is the TextWatcher (though the onFocusChanged might work, but this is another approach). Here is sample code:

```
TextWatcher watcher= new TextWatcher() {
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) { 
            if (TextBox1.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                 TextBox1.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.white));
                 TextBox1.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.black));
            }

        }
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
              //Do something or nothing.                
        }
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            //Do something or nothing
        }
    };

    TextBox1.addTextChangedListener(watcher);
```

Also you will want to do String comparisons using `.equals()`.

Comment: I think you have an idea of what I am looking to do. How would I incorporate that in my code?

Comment: You *should* be able to copy/paste that where you have your other code and just change TextBox1 to the appropriate EditText var.

Comment: The way I did it is I had a different TextWatcher for each EditText.

Comment: What if i just want to remove the RED background instead of changing to white, what code would i edit?

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a removeBackground() method so you would have to set the background to some other color. You can't not have a background color. Even if you don't set the color it is still default white.

Comment: I just changed the textview text color, easier this way :) Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4):

```
txt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtChange);
    txt.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                int count) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(s.toString().trim())) {
                txt.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
            } else
                txt.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can your `TextWatcher`, here is an example:

```
    final EditText et = new EditText(getApplicationContext());

TextWatcher tw = new TextWatcher() {

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
    if (s.length() > 0) {
        et.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
    } else {
        et.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
    }

    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
};

et.addTextChangedListener(tw);
setContentView(et);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is i think absolutely wrong (it compiles?). You need to test content length of field. I don't know exactly what you are trying to do in your code.

Here are two possible approaches:

```
if (TextBox1.getText().toString().length() > 0) {
   // is not empty
}
else {
   // is empty
}

or

if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(TextBox1.getText().toString())) {
   // is not empty
}
else {
   // is empty
}
```